# Create msix package manually without GUI or msi installer

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation, msix

Can anyone give me a hint how I can manually define a msix package? My application has no msi package (yet), so I can’t simply convert it. Is there a way to create like a configuration file where I define manually which files need to go into the msix package? The MSIX GUI Creator doesn’t give me enough control either. Any link or help is highly appreciated

Comment: I haven't done much with MSIX yet but I do wonder, why not just create an MSI to convert?   It shouldn't take more then a few minutes to create one for a simple application.

Comment: I thought of it as well but I decided not to because I don’t want to go the extra route and create something I don’t need - btw the application has a volume of around 6 GB

Comment: I'm wondering to myself out loud... I wonder if MSIX can handle a package that large.  (Not mean to be construed as FUD.)  I know MSI would struggle  requiring the package to have multiple external cabs and possibly  attention to how many components/files you author with various scale concerns.

Comment: I don't feel too competent answering this, but there is the [Advanced Installer Express edition](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html). As Chris says, if you do 6GB as one package, then you can't store the file on FAT32 partitions as far as I know (unless there has been an update of late). Seeing as Windows has required NTFS as system partition for several generations now, I guess you could try anyway, but many USB sticks are still FAT32 I guess.

Comment: And one more link: [MSIX Tutorial](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot . !

Comment: @DanielStephens Added a comment below. And the MSIX GUI Creator you speak of, you mean the free tool that is available in the Windows Store referred to as ["MSIX Packaging Tool"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/mpt-overview)?

Comment: Oh, I need to add that [Firegiant](https://www.firegiant.com/) (WiX's commercial branch) has support for MSIX in the [WiX expansion pack](https://www.firegiant.com/products/wix-expansion-pack/msix/) (not sure of price, support@firegiant.com). It leaves to be seen what WiX4 will support.

Comment: Unsure of Installshield and PACE Suite MSIX support. [Simplified major tools list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the free executable [makeappx.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/appxpkg/make-appx-package--makeappx-exe-) from Microsoft which is able to create *msix* and *appx* packages from a directory where your application is located in

Comment: Great shout, however it doesn't seem to be available anymore (as part of the Windows 8.0 SDK). Inspecting the MsixPackagingTool (from an admin `cmd`) reveals that it's deployed along with it, and copying it out of WindowsApps/ (again as admin) lets you run it. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

As Stein recommended, an easy way is to get the [Express edition](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express-edition.html) from Advanced Installer and just create an empty new project (*not convert an old installer, it can do that too*), and then add in Files and Folders page all the resources you want to include in the package.

In the rest of the views from the project you can define your application details, digital signature configs, capabilities,... basically anything that would would need to manually define in the AppxManifest.xml file you can define through its GUI.

And if you are really [getting started with MSIX, the tutorial](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html) I wrote is also a good reference to start from.

*Disclaimer: I work on the team building Advanced Installer.*

Comment: Not sure if [this YouTube playlist for MSIX Packaging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2avv6SgcNJ4&list=PLhybAX-2L54wZPJBuhRUZjHE8mn9RRS8F) is linked from the content already listed? And [all the Advanced Installer YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/AdvancedInstaller/videos).